# Rooting an ASUS K012

Tags: rooting

I have an ASUS tablet filled with bloatware which I would like to remove very much. I've read about having to root the device, which I am willing, since I think I left some corrupted files when I was about to reinstall an app and I could not delete it with normal access. But I need to know the risks of rooting an ASUS device, if it were the same as rooting a Samsung device of the same OS, or greater.

My OS is Lollipop by the way.

Thank you, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's lollipop you'll have to unlock the bootloader before being able to root.(warranty will be void)
Then you can download a compatible recovery and flash it using fastboot.
You can then use the recovery to install su.
Caution: Unlocking bootloader will clear all the data from your tablet. 
Lemme know if you understand the risk and are willing to do it. I'll write a guide for you if you want.
Here's a wiki link for unlocking the BL:http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Template:Unlock_Bootloader_Asus

Comment: I understand the risks. Thank you. I'm ready. :)

Comment: Actually, the link I provided pretty much acts as a guide which is why edited my answer. Read it and tell me if you don't understand any step.